# Schedule all jobs from the list

Tags: python, apscheduler

I have extracted a list from a database with a format like this:

```
task_list = [
("script_to_run.py", date(2019,8,12), time(10,20), "one time"),
("script2_to_run.py", date(2019,8,12), time(10,30), "daily"),
("script3_to_run.py", date(2019,8,12), time(10,40), "daily")]
```

Now in the for loop I'm trying to combine date and time to set a job for scheduling with APscheduler, but first I want to separate daily and one time jobs:

```
def send_jobs():
    for i in task_list:
        if i[3] =='one time':
            one_time_schedule(i)
        if i[3] =='daily':
             daily_schedule(i)
```

Now, the first task is "one time":

```
def one_time_schedule(row):
    date_time = datetime.combine(row[1],row[2])
    sched.add_jos(function, "date", run_date = date_time)
```

Then in the main:

```
sched = BackgroundSchedule()
send_jobs()
sched.start()
```

Problem is, for me, that program gets into the send_jobs method, identifies the first job, and sends it to the method `one_time_scheduler()`. There the job is added, but the program doesn't return to the next one, the second element in the list, so I finish the program with only one job added instead of many.

The result when printing is:

```
print(shed.get_jobs())
[<Job (id= 5213437jopf56423a name=function)>]
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
from datetime import datetime, date, time

schedule = BackgroundScheduler()


def daily_job(): pass

def one_time_job(): pass


task_list = [
    ('script_to_run.py', date(2019, 8, 12), time(10, 20), 'one time'),
    ('script2_to_run.py', date(2019, 8, 12), time(10, 30), 'daily'),
    ('script3_to_run.py', date(2019, 8, 12), time(10, 40), 'daily')]

for script, task_date, task_time, frequency in task_list:
    if frequency == 'daily':
        run_date = datetime.combine(task_date, task_time)
        schedule.add_job(func=daily_job,
                         trigger='date',
                         run_date=run_date)
    else:       
        schedule.add_job(func=one_time_job,
                         trigger='cron',
                         hour=task_time.hour,
                         minute=task_time.minute)
schedule.start()
```

The output I'm getting is:

```
>> print(schedule.get_jobs())
[<Job (id=13028449c2a44b169fee37dfbacb2742 name=one_time_job)>,
 <Job (id=647e0e2c90ef4e35a3b03dbeec794197 name=daily_job)>,
 <Job (id=65d352d400f64287a80f5cb06fcb5f03 name=daily_job)>]
```

Comment: Thank you for good answer, the thing works, but my question is why my logic does not works, i will need in my program a lot of logic implemented via different functions.

Comment: I see a typo in the method name you are using (add_jos), could you take a look there? Also, can you share the definition of the daily_schedule function, to see why it doesn't do it's job properly?

Comment: that typo is not in the program(add_jobs) , daily schedule is function for the question, for beggining i only use "one time" function.

So the loop is breaking after i goes to one_time_schedule and the line add_job

Comment: Can it be that you end up only with one job because there is only one one_time_job in your test data? Can you run it with more one_time_job tasks in the list? If it doesn't work could, you post your script to see exactly what's going on? Also please consider accepting or upvoting the answer if it works for you.

Comment: And next issue. Even your jobs, they don't run, event dough they are set.
EDIT: i would gladly upwote and i did, but my reputation is not enough for vote to be seen.